# While loop that writes the single name connected to four different courses four times,how to fix

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have an HTML table where I show the name the surname ... ... and the courses of a person, the problem is that when a person has more than one course in the database(like 3 courses) the while loop will write in a row

```
alex alexia ... ...  course 1
alex alexia ... ... course 2
alex alexia... ... course 3
```

If you can help me to group the courses and the names in one line, with showing all them, because if I use group by it shows one name, but only one course(not all)
I tried to do it with using a flag column on the table Personale that is set to 1 if a row its wrote but it doesn't work

```
$formazione=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT Formazione.Data_Formazione,Personale.*,Corso.*  FROM Formazione NATURAL JOIN Personale NATURAL JOIN Corso  ORDER BY Personale.Nome ASC;");
while (($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($formazione))){ 
   $flagPersonale=$row2['Flag_Personale'];
   $idPersonale=$row2['ID_Personale'];
   $aggFormazione=$row2['Aggiornamento_Formazione'];
   $nomeCorso=$row2['Nome_Corso'];
   $dataFormazione=$row2['Data_Formazione'];
   $nome=$row2["Nome"];
   $cognome=$row2["Cognome"];
   $ruolo=$row2["Ruolo"];
   $plesso=$row2["Plesso"]; 
   $flagCorso=$row2["Flag_Corso"];
   $nomEcogn=$nome+$cognome;
   if($flagPersonale==0){
   $inserimento = "UPDATE Personale SET Flag_Personale = 1
   WHERE ID_Personale = $idPersonale";
   if(mysqli_query($conn, $inserimento)) {
    echo "<tr><td class=\"$nome\" id=\"$nome\">";
    echo "<input id=\"$nomEcogn\" type=\"text\" class =\"it\" value=\"$nome\" 
    readonly=\"readonly\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" class =\"it\" 
    value=\"$cognome\" readonly=\"readonly\"></td><td><input type=\"text\" 
    class =\"it\" value=\"$ruolo\" readonly=\"readonly\"></td><td><input 
    type=\"text\" class =\"it\" value=\"$plesso\" readonly=\"readonly\"></td> 
    <td><input type=\"text\" class =\"it\" value=\"$nomeCorso\" 
    readonly=\"readonly\"> <button id=\"modifica\"><button id=\"Elimina\"></td> 
    </tr>";     
  } 
  else {
    echo" mysqli_connect_error()";
  }
}
```

I just want to do display alex   alexia ... ... course 1,course2,course3 in a  single row, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, consider an aggregate query using [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function which can return a list of items. Please adjust your query to below specification. Please properly adhere to the SQL rules of `GROUP BY` (which depending on settings, MySQL can diverge) (i.e., follow [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) setting).

```sql
SELECT p.name, p.surname, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(course SEPARATOR ',') AS course_list
FROM persons p
JOIN courses c 
  ON p.person_id = c.person_id
GROUP BY p.name, p.surname
```

This might involve joining to your unit level query as posted above.

```sql
SELECT f.Data_Formazione, p.*, agg.course_list 
FROM Formazione f
NATURAL JOIN Personale p
INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT c.person_id, GROUP_CONCAT(course SEPARATOR ',') AS course_list
    FROM courses c ON 
    GROUP BY c.person_id
   ) AS agg
  ON agg.person_id = p.person_id
ORDER BY p.Nome ASC;
```

Then, in PHP, you can `explode` the comma-separated list of courses into an array:

```
$courses_array = explode(",", $sql_data['course_list']);
```